# Layout larger than device screen causes app to crash

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I am currently having an issue with a mobile app I am developing. The idea behind it being it displays the value of various variables from a passed object. As I have needed to add more and more objects to the layout xml file in order to display everything, the preview has since stopped displaying any objects besides the action bar and trying to start the activity using this layout crashes the app.

I have a feeling this may be due to the layout being larger than the virtual device screen, though there could be another cause i'm totally unaware of. Any help in this matter would be appreciated. This activity currently uses the Relative layout, would it resolve the issue to wrap the Relative layout in a Scrollview to make the activity scrollable?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/RequestNameTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/RequestNameDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestNameTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Student ID"
    android:id="@+id/RequestStudentIDTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestNameDisplay"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/RequestStudentIDDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestStudentIDTextView"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/RequestLocationTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestStudentIDDisplay"
    android:text="Location"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/RequestLocationDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestLocationTextView"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/RequestProblemTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestLocationDisplay"
    android:text="Problem Description"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/RequestProblemDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestProblemTextView"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/RequestStatusTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestProblemDisplay"
    android:text="Current Status"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/RequestStatusDisplay"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestStatusTextView"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/RequestAssignmentTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestStatusDropDown"
    android:text="Assigned To"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/RequestAssignmentDisplay"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestAssignmentTextView"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/RequestStatusUpdateTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestAssignmentDisplay"
    android:text="Update Status to:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/RequestStatusDropDown"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestStatusUpdateTextView"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/RequestAssignmentUpdateTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestStatusDropDown"
    android:text="Assign Request To:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/RequestAssignmentDropDown"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RequestAssignmentUpdateTextView"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/RequestSaveChangesButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Save Changes" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your Relative Layout having Circular dependencies. From RequestAssignmentTextView to RequestStatusDropDown, your are having a circular dependency. Just change your 'below' element of RequestAssignmentTextView to avoid this error.

Comment: Thank you, after testing this seems to resolve the issue. I credit you for being able to pick up on the circular dependency despite the lack of exception details, guess I should be more careful when asking for help at 4AM!